# How to exclude navigation properties validations from model state on web api

Tags: odata, asp.net-web-api2, asp.net-mvc-5.1

I am using Asp.net MVC 5 with Web API 2 and OData. I am using ODataControllers in web api. I have a contact class which have a navigation property company and company have a required attribute on its name property. On web api contact controller's post action i am checking ModelState.IsValid before saving the data. Now Problem is that when i post contact data on web api its ModelState.IsValid property returns false every time because Company Navigation Property have a property Name with Required attribute. so Model state throws error Name field is required. So please help me to exclude company navigation property from validation check. Hoping for some positive responses.
Thanks

Comment: Can you share the model and the request body so that I can repro the issue. Thanks

Comment: Since the property is required, it makes sense that it should show up in the navigation property. Otherwise there should have no navigation in the body.

Comment: @FengZhao-MSFT Thanks for the reply. I found the main cause of this problem which is in the 2nd answer. Please check that. Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

@FengZhao-MSFT Thanks for your reply but i found the main cause of this problem. This is occuring because when i am posting contact object it also sends company="", companyID=1 in posted data where company is navigation property of contact. so this company="" is creating the problem due to this when data goes to post method it creates a new instance of company and throws model state error for name field required. If we remove company="" from our posted data and only sends companyID problem solves. One more thing we are using   a common ajax post method for all our resources so we can't exclude comapny="" from our request. Now we have excluded it on server side using actionfilter where we have removed company validation errors from modelstate. Thanks

Answer (score 3):

dudes!

I notices that ten years left ))

Add
ModelState.Remove("Company");
or better
ModelState.Remove(nameof(YourModelName.Company));

to your Controller Post (Create) method, before ModelState.IsValid() check

it's a kind of workaround... "normal" way id to use separate DTO class for addition

Comment: Ran into this too. Somewhere else was suggested to remove `<Nullable>enable</Nullable>` from the `csproj` file causing problems with timestamp (rowversion) fields. Will keep an eye on this, if there are no side effects.

Answer (score 1):

I'm having the same issue.
Actually this type of issue only occurs in OdataController. MvcController action ignores navigation property validations.

Comment: Yes i think it is happening due to odata controller but i am stuck at this point so if you found solution for this then please reply.

Answer (score 0):

Yes, you are right. `company=""` is the root cause of the problem.

I don't know how to work with ajax post method, but can you try changing `company=""` to `company=null`, then the request body should be like

```
{
....
"company":null
...
}
```

I think this request will work. *(I don't know whether ajax can do this.)*

Answer (score 0):

No "company":null did not worked. It is also creating company object similar to "company":"" so only solution is posting ajax request without sending "company" in data.